# How to resolve " throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event ^ Error: spawn cp ENOENT" error?

Tags: node.js, npm, child-process

I am trying to copy `master.js` into `master1.js`.

Getting the following error:

```
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^Error: spawn cp ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:240:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:415:16)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

**Code for master.js**

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

const child = spawn('cp',["master.js","master1.js"]);
child.on("exit",()=>{
    console.log("copy finished")
})
```

Comment: Which OS you are using? I am successfully able to copy the file. No issue at all.

Comment: Check this out: https://repl.it/repls/InterestingLongExternalcommand just click on the run button

Comment: I am using windows 10.